# OAuth 2.0 protocol in native Apps, e.g. Instagram

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth, instagram-api

I am currently building an API for my native App and want to implement the OAuth 2.0 protocol for authentication. If I take a look at companies like Instagram, Facebook or Twitter I wonder how they are handling the authentication process of their **own** native App (not third-party).

So Instagram for example is using the OAuth 2.0 protocol to protect their API endpoints ([here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/)). Related to their developer platform they offer you - as a third-party developer - the possibility to use their API and authenticate your own App via **Server-side (Explicit)** or **Implicit** flow. All of these flows require the user to authenticate via an **In-App browser** (or system browser).

Like I said before, I am wondering how these Apps are handling the authentication in their own Apps. The user doesn't get redirected to any browser to authenticate. They could use the **Explicit** flow and store the client_id and client_secret for example in Keychain (iOS). But Instagram is telling third-party developers "***You should never pass or store your client_id secret onto a client. For these situations there is the Implicit Authentication Flow.***".

I don't want the user to get redirected in my own App. The user should be able to use a login/signup form within the native App.

Does anyone have an idea or insides on how Instagram etc. are doing it? I am really curious and appreciate any helpful answer. :)

Comment: I am not an expert on the subject, but I guess these native applications may probably be using the "Resource Owner Password" flow. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.3